# Merging mbtiles databases

Tags: gdalwarp, mbtiles

I have a large set of hires GeoTif images.

I am trying to build a .mbtiles database of these images. However, using gdalbuildvrt and osgearth_conv makes me hit a wall. I have also tried using gdalwarp with various compression options, to build one large geotiff that I serve to osgearth_conv instead of a virtual .vrt set. Same result, unreasonable processing time.

So, I am trying to work around the problem by creating multiple smaller .mbtiles databases and then merge them. But I am doing something wrong. The result is not smooth.

[image: Visible gap.]

I went about doing the merge by using DB Browser (SQLite) and inserted tiles by:

```
PRAGMA journal_mode=PERSIST;
PRAGMA page_size=80000;
PRAGMA synchronous=OFF;
ATTACH DATABASE 'C:\pathto\database.mbtiles' AS source;
REPLACE INTO tiles SELECT * FROM source.tiles;
```

Then, I changed the bounds metadata accordingly:

> bounds -5.39167,52.1156,33.2851,67.9002

The profile metadata remains the same.

Am I going about this the wrong way?